# how to use tensorboard debugger with datalab which uses tf.estimator on google cloud platform

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorboard, google-cloud-datalab

When I start tensorboard via datalab it uses the google syntax which is described [here](https://googledatalab.github.io/pydatalab/google.datalab.ml.html).  This document only mentions start, stop and list.  However, there is a debugger pane which I can not use.

[This](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/tree/master/tensorboard/plugins/debugger) document describes how to use tensorboard debugger with a tf.estimator but it uses a different syntax.

Is there someway to blend the two so the debugger is usable with datalab?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can run tfdbg in datalab.  You can take the code and run it at the console like so using this [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/debugger#debugging_tensorflow_estimators):

1. I am using the datalab notebook which uses a model.py and task.py.   My code originally was modeled after this [file](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/machine_learning/deepdive/03_tensorflow/e_cloudmle.ipynb).
2. Make this change to the `model.py` code as shown in the guide mentioned above.

   ```
   from tensorflow.python import debug as tf_debug
   # for debugging
   hooks = [tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugHook()]
   ```

Then in the `train_and_evaluate(args)` routine add a reference to the hooks in the parameter list for the `EvalSpec()` call.  Like so:

```
    # .. also need an EvalSpec which controls the evaluation and
    # the checkpointing of the model since they happen at the same time
    eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
        input_fn = read_dataset(
            args['eval_data_paths'],
            batch_size = 10000,  # original 10000
            mode = tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL),
        steps=None, # evals on 100 batches
        start_delay_secs = args['eval_delay_secs'], # start evaluating after N secoonds. 
        throttle_secs = args['min_eval_frequency'], # eval no more than every N seconds.
        exporters = exporter,# how to export the model for production.
        hooks = hooks) # for the debugger
```

Then using your pereferred virtual python environment, do the following: (I am using anaconda)

1. Open a python 2.7 environment with anaconda

   ```
   $ . ~/bin/setenv-anaconda2.sh
   ```
2. Activate the tensorflow python2.7 anaconda environment

   ```
   $ conda activate tensorflow
   ```
3. get the gcloud environment

   ```
   $ . ~/progs/datalab-notebooks/bin/setenv_google.sh
   ```
4. For this model, set a python path to find modules

   ```
   cd ~/progs/datalab-notebooks/tf-debug
   export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${PWD}/taxisimple
   ```

Then this to train:  --train_steps=1000. appears to be max steps.

```
python -m trainer.task \
   --train_data_paths="${PWD}/taxi-train*" \
   --eval_data_paths=${PWD}/taxi-valid.csv  \
   --output_dir=${PWD}/taxi_trained \
   --train_steps=1000 --job-dir=./tmp
```

This will give you a tftdbg prompt.  From here you can explore the model using tfdbg.